# Conditional Format is not working for Times

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to format the cells to where if the time remaining in the V column is greater than the time in the X column (6:55) it should highlight red. For some reason, it is not working. Is there a workaround?

[image: See Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Convert the value in cell X7 to **number of hours** using `TIMEVALUE()*24`, then you can use this custom formula below as comparison. In Format cells dropdown choose `Custom Formula`.

```
=$V5-$X$7>0
```

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: Looks like its highlighting everything for me actually. Even the numbers lower. Should I format the time to end in 0's like yours?

Comment: I also noticed that when I change the format to number for 6:55 its a negative number. Could this be the cause? Maybe I need to change how I calculate the time remaining

Comment: Now that I think about it more. The column with all of the "hours remaining" in the  V column was converted from a number. Those were calculated by volume/hourly rate. so if there are 1000 units to produce and they do 100/hr, they would take 10 hours to complete so it would be 10. I then changed the format to time, but I don't think that was the best way to do it. Which may explain why yours works and mine doesnt.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a decimal number to hours properly?

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet? It looks like your values are not time format. What does it look like when you convert everything to number?

Comment: Unfortunately its propritetary. I also found out that the formulas in column V are not doing what I needed to do, so ill have to revisit this issue.

Comment: A simple mockup will do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AtpuS7RUiRVB--Oe72o48UcO0wQDdQXu361Bn1AdzT0/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please share to Public / Anyone with the link.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please let me know if this works on your original sheet.

Comment: Very much appreciated! :)